# Too much recursion while performing .next in jQuery 1.3.2

Tags: jquery

I've just upgraded to jQuery 1.3.2, which has mostly been fine, but I'm missing something when it comes to the new event model (I think)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $(".AspNet-Menu-NonLink").click(function()
    {
        $(this).next($("ul")).slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $(".AspNet-Menu-NonLink").next($("ul")).hide();
    $(".AspNet-Menu-ChildSelected").next($("ul")).show();
});
```

This used to work, but the error "too much recursion" is popping out on this line:

```
$(".AspNet-Menu-NonLink").next($("ul")).hide();
```

How can this cause recursion, hide() hides something, what's to go wrong?

**UPDATE**

I've discovered that if I remove the references to jQuery UI 1.7.1 script library the problem goes away. Even if I'm not calling anything in the jQuery UI library, but have it included I get the error.

Answer (score 6):

For starters, try using

```
$(".AspNet-Menu-NonLink").next("ul").hide();
```

Instead.

Otherwise, you're implicitly searching for, and returning *all* `ul` elements on the page and then passing that *massive* result to the "`next`" function.

According to the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/next#overview), '`next`' takes a string, an expression, that is used to filter its traversal.

`$("ul")` however, executes a DOM query and returns a jQuery object.

Comment: That's helpful, I must have missunderstood the original docs.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of this:

```
$(".AspNet-Menu-NonLink").next($("ul")).hide();
```

try this:

```
$(".AspNet-Menu-NonLink").next("ul").hide();
```

When calling `next()`, you only need to pass a CSS selector string, not an entire jQuery object. Documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/next#expr

jQuery UI may be at fault because, when it's imported into your application, it overrides the standard jQuery `hide()` function. See line 3812 in the source: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.js